# Ninject syntax for "Bind" with multiple arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

How I can use multiple parameters in Ninject syntax like following?

```
Bind<IMyRepository>()
.To<SqlMyRepository>()
.WithConstructorArgument("connectionString",
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDb"].ConnectionString
 );
```

What if more than one parameter need to be passed?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can chain the calls to `WithConstructorArgument`:

```
Bind<IMyRepository>()
    .To<SqlMyRepository>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDb"].ConnectionString)
    .WithConstructorArgument("timeout", 10000);
```

Comment: if your argument name changes in the ctor, you won't get a compile error and ninject will fail to bind.

Comment: @seabass this is the downside of dependency injection, the flexibility of defining things at runtime _can_ cause runtime errors. Integration testing should help flush them out.