# Ninject setter method returns null

Tags: c#, ninject, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to make an injection using Setter Method. However what I always have is a null reference exception.

```
public class CustomOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private IMembershipService _membershipService;

    [Inject]
    public void SetMembershipService(IMembershipService membershipService)
    {
        _membershipService = membershipService;
    }

    //Code omitted
}
```

I'm not using constructor injection because CustomOAuth provider is used in instantiating OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions, and in this case I would have to pass a parameter in constructor somehow -

```
var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
    Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
    AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["owin:issuer"])
};
```

Ninject module -

```
Bind<IMembershipService>().To<MembershipService>();
```

Comment: is the CustomOAuthProvider actually being instanciated by ninject? Remark: Passing the `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` is not such a big deal, you can create a binding for `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` (specific for `CustomOAuthProvider` or you can create a more specific binding for `CustomOAuthProvider` with a parameter to be injected (the options).

Comment: No, `CustomOAuthProvider` is not instantiated by ninject. Should it be? Could you please elaborate about, passing parameters to be injected? I found an example  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686734/ninject-syntax-for-bind-with-multiple-arguments

However I'm not sure if it is what I should be taking as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inject something into an instance which is not instanciated by ninject, you need to call

```
kernel.Inject(..instance...);
```

after the object has been created. Why? Ninject does not magically know when objects are created. So if it's not creating the object itself, you need to tell it about the object.

referring to your comment, this is one of the options to bind `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions`:

```
Bind<OAuthorizationServerOptions>().ToConstant(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
        AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(
           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["owin:issuer"])
    })
.WhenInjectedInto<CustomOAuthProvider>();
```

Then `WhenInjectedInto` makes sure these options are only used when creating an `CustomOAuthProvider`. In case you're always (only) using the `CustomOAuthProvider` you can probably remove then `When..` condition.