# Is there any way for the nameof operator to access method parameters (outside of the same method)?

Tags: c#, metadata, c#-6.0, nameof

Take the following class and method:

```
public class Foo
    public Foo Create(string bar) {
        return new Foo(bar);
    }
```

So getting "Create" is obvious: `nameof(Foo.Create)`

Is there any way to get "bar" other than using reflection to read the parameters at run time?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want that?

Comment: @PauloMorgado i'm flowing json directly through my system with as minimal typing as possible. I like that in my tests i can easily signify the relationship between a property and it's json name.............................. `$"{nameof(Person.Name)}:chris, foo:bar"` (i'm in a comment box, this isn't a literal copy & paste but general idea). It's harder to express this relationship between a json property-name & value pair and the relationship to a method's argument's name & type pair. I'm tired of the never ending mapping layers when all i wanted was the direct input.

Comment: @PauloMorgado One very useful case would be IoC container Bootstrapping, like [Ninject's `WithConstructorArgument`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3687224/314291) taking a reflected string literal parameter name - any change to the method signature, and boom! the bootstrapping breaks. It would have been ideal to have used `nameof(Class.Method.Parameter)` instead.

Comment: This is [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/373) on C# github, those who feel strongly enough about it can upvote it so that it gets implemented in the future versions of C#

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No. There is no way to get the parameter names from the outside of the method using `nameof`. `nameof` doesn't work for method parameters if you want the name on the calling side (for the callee it does work obviously). The other methods you mentioned, like reflection, do work.

```
var parameterNames = typeof(Program)
                     .GetMethod(nameof(Program.Main)).GetParameters()
                     .Select(p => p.Name);
```