Is it possible to get the name of a C# method parameter without having to use "magic strings"?
I'm using Ninject as my IoC container. I have a few instances where I need to configure the injected service at runtime, so I need to pass in constructor arguments. I'm currently doing something like this:
var service = Kernel.Get<MyService>(new ConstructorArgument("paramName", runtimeInstance);

The injected parameter "paramName" is a magic string that is not refactoring-friendly nor strongly-typed.
Is there a way to somehow use nameof(aMethodParameter), or an equivalent expression, to get the name of the constructor parameter so that it's no longer a "magic string"?

Can't you use nameof(OriginalType.aMethodParameter) ? Or I'm not getting what you mean?

I think the only way you could do that would be to use Reflection. I'm not sure that you can even use nameof for a parameter within the method - never tried for local variables - but you certainly couldn't do it outside because that variable would not be in scope..

@jmcilhinney how could a solution using reflection be made refactoring-friendly?

For a solution with reflection can you be sure about the position of the parameter? With reflection we might be able to ask for the name of the "first" parameter. Or would reflection in combination with a refactoring effort just break differently for you? So in the end switching from a magic string to a magic number?

check https://stackoverflow.com/a/37350136/6908545

@Ralf, I'm not sure whether the parameters are guaranteed to be returned in the same order as they appear in the method signature, but each ParameterInfo has a Position property, so you could order by that. If you write code that doesn't assume any names, positions or even the number of parameters then it will be refactoring-friendly.
